# How to read outlook 2007 categories using c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, outlook, outlook-2007

I am using .net framework 3.5 by using C# to configure outlook 2007
I need to import all categories from outlook  2007 to my application particularly on dropdownlist, i want to listed all the categories 
from outlook to one combobox in my application, i don't know how to get all the categories,

if anyone know reply

Answer (score 1):

In a new 'Office' type project in visual studio (Outlook AddIn):

```
NameSpace nameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

foreach(var cat in nameSpace.Categories)
{
      //Add cat to your combo box      
}
```